# How to make a toggle button to add and "remove" from DOM a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ms-word, toggle

I made a toggle button to add and remove a div. It works well (see code snippet)

I want to export to MSword the div added. I'm using "filesaver.js" and "jquery.wordexport.js". It works well too. Using another button, it gets me the added div to a downloadable word (.docx)

Now, if I click the button to add the div and download the .docx, the added div do appear on the .docx. If I don't click it, the .docx is blank (good so far)

**My problem is**: If I click the "add div" button and then click it again (to make the div disappear), it won't get removed from the .docx, when I download it.

I wonder if it is because on my javascript there is not the function ".remove" specifically. I'm new to this, sorry.

Here's the add/remove div button

```js
$(function(){
    var NewContent='<div class="added">HELLO</div>'
    $(".addremove").one('click', function(){
    var $content =  $(NewContent).appendTo('.toadd');
    $(this).click(function(){
    $content.toggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toadd">
  <button type="button" class="addremove">Add / Remove</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding/removing the element itself from the container each time, rather than simply hiding/showing it, which leaves the element in the DOM:

```js
$(function(){
    let NewContent='<div class="added">HELLO</div>'
    let added = false;
    let $content;
    $(".addremove").on('click', function(){
      if (!added) $content =  $(NewContent).appendTo('.toadd');
      else $content.remove();
      added = !added;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toadd">
  <button type="button" class="addremove">Add / Remove</button>
</div>
```